# Vue + Laravel sanctum CSRF token mismatch 419 error

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I get a "419 (unknown status)" error with the message "CSRF token mismatch."

[POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/login 419 (unknown status)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TlSP.png)

[CSRF token mismatch.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9L6si.png)

Laravel server : http://127.0.0.1:8000

Vue server : http://localhost:8080

app/Http/Kernel.php

```php
'api' => [
    \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
    'throttle:api',
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

app/Models/User.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    //...
}
```

config/cors.php

```php
<?php

return [
    'paths' => [
        'api/*',
        'sanctum/csrf-cookie',
        'register',
        'login',
    ],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,
];
```

.env

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8080
```

src/main.js

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
    config.withCredentials = true

    return config
})
```

src/views/auth/Login.vue

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import { reactive } from '@vue/reactivity';

export default {
    setup() {

        const credential = reactive({
            email: '',
            password: '',
        })

        const login = async () => {
            axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then( async () => {
                let response = await axios.post('/login', credential)
                console.log(response);
            });
        }

        return { login, credential }
    }
};
```

Comment: Just as a note to my future self, make sure your `SESSION_DRIVER` is set to `cookie` in your `.env` file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have your `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` set to `localhost:8080`, but the rest of the code shows you're running on port 8000 instead of 8080. If you change that to 8000 you should be golden.

Answer (score 34):

I had a hard time dealing with this same issue. After several searches, I landed on this page. Having seen possible suggested solutions, I changed

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8080
```

to

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=http://localhost:8080
```

And that was it! It worked fine!!

Comment: It took way too long to figure out that this was causing this

Comment: I... I... just can't believe that! It solved the problem I've been over 3 hours! Didn't they think it is important to document such behaviour in a visible way, as the sample codes point to exactly the opposite?

Comment: I'm confused about this, all docs that i found state that the protocol shouldn't be included. If I add it on my Laravel instance, it works, but not completely...

Comment: I want to give you 1 million ups.

Comment: Thanks @Aluefua Ehiabhi, I spent hours trying to make this work until I saw your answer. This is definitely another miss or failure in Laravel's documentation.

Comment: man i was stucked on it for days, and your comment solved my problem, just add `http://` and works thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#cors-and-cookies) documentation

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.withXSRFToken = true;
```

In my case, I forgot to set the `axios.defaults.withXSRFToken = true;`, after that everything was working fine.